# TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python

I wanted to apply simple function which checks whether a day is business day, I'm pulling data from Excel:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['date'] = df['date'].dt.date
df['is_bd'] = np.is_busday(df['date'])
```

It throws me an error. I understand there is type error for my 'date' column but no idea which is correct to use in this case :

```
TypeError: Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('<M8[us]') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is busday is taking 'date' as an argument, but you are using 'datetime' - this is why you have this issue, you should get just date from your ['date'] column, and then use is_busday on it.

Also you can simply use numpy function, no reason to create another function around it.

Comment: Do you mean like this? df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date and then call numpy function on it? df['is_bd'] = np.is_busday(df['date']). That returns the same error.

Comment: I mean that by using to_datetime you are getting datetimes in your pandas column - this wont work with numpy 'is_busday' - the option is to get date only - you can do dt.date as you suggested :)

Comment: I managed to do it. Basically, the date column has to be converted into string, which is little bit surprising. Therefore, df['Is_bd'] = [np.is_busday(x) for x in df['date'].astype(str)]